# Kubernetes keeps creating objects

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Being new to the K8s, I am trying to clean up the whole namespace after running some tests on a Windows 10 machine. In short, I thought it would be as easy as running kubectl.exe delete deployment but the deployments are created back after a second and I don't know how to get rid of them. See the followings for the details of what I did:

*`1.kubectl get deployments,rs`* (to see what we already have)

```
NAME                               DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE AGE
deployment.extensions/postgresql   1         1         1            1           18m
deployment.extensions/redis        1         1         1            1           16m
NAME                                         DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     AGE  
replicaset.extensions/postgresql-c8cb9fff6   1         1         1         18m
replicaset.extensions/redis-5678477b7c       1         1         1         16m
```

*`2. kubectl scale deployment redis --replicas=0`* (Scale down the deployment)

```
deployment.extensions "redis" scaled
```

*`3. kubectl get deployments,rs`* (Check again how it looks)

```
NAME                               DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.extensions/postgresql   1         1         1            1           21m
deployment.extensions/redis        0         0         0            0           19m
NAME                                         DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     AGE
replicaset.extensions/postgresql-c8cb9fff6   1         1         1         21m
replicaset.extensions/redis-5678477b7c       0         0         0         19m
```

*`4. kubectl delete deployment.extensions/redis`* (Delete the deployment)

```
deployment.extensions "redis" deleted
```

*`5. kubectl get deployments,rs`* (Check again and see that it is back!)

```
NAME                               DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.extensions/postgresql   1         1         1            1           23m
deployment.extensions/redis        1         1         1            1           27s  
NAME                                         DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     AGE
replicaset.extensions/postgresql-c8cb9fff6   1         1         1         23m
replicaset.extensions/redis-5678477b7c       1         1         1         27s
```

*`6. kubectl.exe get events` (Looking into the events):*
Among other things I can see "Scaled down replica set redis-5678477b7c to 0" and then "Scaled up replica set redis-5678477b7c to 1" which looks like it was never actually deleted but immediately scaled up again after the delete command was executed.

Not sure what I am missing but have already checked a couple of other posts like [Kubernetes pod gets recreated when deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40686151/kubernetes-pod-gets-recreated-when-deleted) and [How to delete all resources from Kubernetes one time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47128586/how-to-delete-all-resources-from-kubernetes-one-time) but neither one worked for me.

Forgot to say that the K8s cluster is managed by the Docker Desktop.

Comment: try `kubectl delete -f redis_deployment.yml`

Comment: In step 4 it looks like you're not deleting the Deployment, you're deleting the intermediate ReplicaSet that's managed by the Deployment.  Does `kubectl delete deployment` there work?  (Mostly you can totally ignore the ReplicaSet objects.)

Comment: @DavidMaze yes, forgot to add to the original post; I had tried both deleting the deployment and the replicaset and the result is still the same.

Comment: `kubecetl delete statefulset --all`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `kubectl delete deployment <the name of deployment >`
2. If you need to clean up whole namespace , use `kubectl delete namespace <namespace-name>`
3. Then re-create the same namespace by `kubectl create ns` command , if you need the same namespace.
4. You can also clean up the namespace by using --all options with objects:

e.g

```
   kubecetl delete deployment --all
   kubecetl delete statefulset --all
   kubectl delete pvc --all
   kubectl delete secrets --all
   kubectl delete service --all
```

and so on.

As pointed out by **@David Maze**, you're deleting the [ReplicaSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/) instead of the [Deployment that's managing it](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/).

From the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/):

> You can define Deployments to create new ReplicaSets

The Deployment will automatically create and manage a ReplicaSet to control the pods. You need to delete the Deployment to erase it's managed resources.

Comment: Those objects belong to the "default" namespace which is forbidden and may not be deleted :( Do you know any way to delete the default ns?

Comment: It might be best if you delete the deployment instead of the namespace.

Comment: @RaminToussi 4th option added for that in the answer.

Comment: it is recommended not to create stuff in default namespace , create custom namespace for everything so that its easyt o clean up later, plus other reasons as well

Comment: @IjazAhmadKhan as I corrected in my post, even deleting the deployment did not help. But I agree with you other comment about creating a separate namespace, that is a good practice to always follow.

Comment: @RaminToussi ok i think  it maybe a statefulset , please paste the output of all the obejcts that you have created in default namespace so that i know what u need to delete , answer update for delete statefulset

Comment: `kubecetl delete statefulset --all`

Comment: if you have deployed things using helm , you need to do `helm delete --purge <name of the chart>`