# Delete all kubernetes resources using client-go?

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

Is it possible to delete all resources with specific label using client go? The version of client-go is 0.17.3

I see in the client that there is a field for every resource type but they have different interfaces.

```
type Clientset struct {
    *discovery.DiscoveryClient
    admissionregistrationV1alpha1 *admissionregistrationv1alpha1.AdmissionregistrationV1alpha1Client
    admissionregistrationV1beta1  *admissionregistrationv1beta1.AdmissionregistrationV1beta1Client
    appsV1beta1                   *appsv1beta1.AppsV1beta1Client
    appsV1beta2                   *appsv1beta2.AppsV1beta2Client
    appsV1                        *appsv1.AppsV1Client
    auditregistrationV1alpha1     *auditregistrationv1alpha1.AuditregistrationV1alpha1Client
    authenticationV1              *authenticationv1.AuthenticationV1Client
    authenticationV1beta1         *authenticationv1beta1.AuthenticationV1beta1Client
    authorizationV1               *authorizationv1.AuthorizationV1Client
    authorizationV1beta1          *authorizationv1beta1.AuthorizationV1beta1Client
    autoscalingV1                 *autoscalingv1.AutoscalingV1Client
    autoscalingV2beta1            *autoscalingv2beta1.AutoscalingV2beta1Client
    autoscalingV2beta2            *autoscalingv2beta2.AutoscalingV2beta2Client
    batchV1                       *batchv1.BatchV1Client
    batchV1beta1                  *batchv1beta1.BatchV1beta1Client
    batchV2alpha1                 *batchv2alpha1.BatchV2alpha1Client
    certificatesV1beta1           *certificatesv1beta1.CertificatesV1beta1Client
    coordinationV1beta1           *coordinationv1beta1.CoordinationV1beta1Client
    coreV1                        *corev1.CoreV1Client
    eventsV1beta1                 *eventsv1beta1.EventsV1beta1Client
    extensionsV1beta1             *extensionsv1beta1.ExtensionsV1beta1Client
    networkingV1                  *networkingv1.NetworkingV1Client
    policyV1beta1                 *policyv1beta1.PolicyV1beta1Client
    rbacV1                        *rbacv1.RbacV1Client
    rbacV1beta1                   *rbacv1beta1.RbacV1beta1Client
    rbacV1alpha1                  *rbacv1alpha1.RbacV1alpha1Client
    schedulingV1alpha1            *schedulingv1alpha1.SchedulingV1alpha1Client
    schedulingV1beta1             *schedulingv1beta1.SchedulingV1beta1Client
    settingsV1alpha1              *settingsv1alpha1.SettingsV1alpha1Client
    storageV1beta1                *storagev1beta1.StorageV1beta1Client
    storageV1                     *storagev1.StorageV1Client
    storageV1alpha1               *storagev1alpha1.StorageV1alpha1Client
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this (got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47128586/how-to-delete-all-resources-from-kubernetes-one-time)):

```
kubectl delete "$(kubectl api-resources --verbs=delete -o name | tr "\n" "," | sed -e 's/,$//')" --all
```

But using the client-go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do anything that kubectl does on your own, using client-go.  After all, kubectl uses client-go itself.

You can look at the [kubectl source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl) to see how it does the following:

1. Get a list of api resources that support the delete verb. See the [api-resources command implementation](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/master/pkg/cmd/apiresources/apiresources.go) for how to do this.
2. For each resource found, get a list of objects that have the label and value you are looking for. Check out [kubectl's get command implementation](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/master/pkg/cmd/get/get.go) for how to do this
3. Delete each object matching the criteria. See [kubectl's delete command implementation](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/master/pkg/cmd/delete/delete.go) for this.

Comment: This answer is really just links. Adding a some code would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry you didn't find my answer helpful enough.  I did provide links, but they are permalinks directly to the relevant parts of the kubernetes code base.  You are welcome to take the information I've provided and submit an answer that includes a code example and perhaps others will find it helpful.